# Multiple directives in same element operating on visibility

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-directive, ng-show, angularjs-controlleras

I have been struggling with my approach for the following scenario.
I have a custom directive `authorize` where I pass the name of a group. If the current user has this group in his profile then the element will be visible, if not the element will be hidden.
Example:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" role="button"
        ng-click="myVm.edit()"
        authorize="{{myVm.groupName}}"><!--groupName = "accountants"-->
    <span class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span> Edit
</button>
```

and my original directive in typescript `authorize.ts` using the link function (because I operate on the DOM)

```
namespace app.blocks.directives {
    "use strict";

    class AuthorizeDirective implements ng.IDirective {

        public restrict: string = "A";

        public replace: boolean = true;

        constructor(private $compile: ng.ICompileService, private authService: services.IAuthService) {
        }

        public static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
            const directive = ($compile: ng.ICompileService, authService: services.IAuthService) =>
                new AuthorizeDirective($compile, authService);
            directive.$inject = [
                "$compile",
                "app.services.AuthService"
            ];
            return directive;
        }

        public link(scope: ng.IScope, instanceElement: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, instanceAttributes: ng.IAttributes): void {
            let groupName: string = (<any>instanceAttributes).authorize;
            let element = angular.element(instanceElement);
            let hasGroup: boolean = this.authService.hasGroup(groupName);
            element.attr("ng-show", String(hasGroup));
            //remove the attribute, otherwise it creates an infinite loop.
            element.removeAttr("authorize");
            this.$compile(element)(scope);
            }
        }
    }

    angular
        .module("app.blocks.directives")
        .directive("authorize", AuthorizeDirective.factory());
}
```

This is working fine, the button is hidden if the authService returns false because the user does not belong to that group (i.e: `"accountants"`).

The problem appears when my DOM element has `ng-show` or `ng-hide` directives also. Example:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" role="button"
        ng-hide="myVm.isDeleted"
        ng-click="myVm.edit()"
        authorize="{{myVm.groupName}}">
    <!--groupName = "accountants"-->
    <span class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span> Edit
</button>
```

When `myVm.isDeleted = true` it seems that overrides the result of my directive and the DOM element is displayed (when it shouldn't because the user does not belong to the specified group as per my `authorize` directive).

I realize there is some priority (by default `0`) in directives, when two directives have the same priority they are executed in alphabetical order according to the documentation. [This post](http://www.newyyz.com/blog/2014/12/15/understanding-priorities-in-angularjs-directive-definition-objects/) was very helpful to understand that.

So I have some options here:

1. Have my authorize directive evaluate the conditional in `ng-hide` or `ng-show` in order to compute (i.e: if the ng-hide says that the element should be shown but the user has not the specific group, then the element should be hidden). **I could not find a way to access `myVm.isDeleted` within my directive link's function**. If anyone know how I'd be happy with this approach.
2. Have my `authorize` directive executed BEFORE any other directive and rely on angular to later on determine visibility according to `ng-show` or `ng-hide` (i.e: if my `authorize` directive determines that the element should be hidden because the user does not belong to the given group, then it should transform the DOM element and make it `ng-show="false"` for example, so that angular hides the element later on. This approach does not seem to work, **the DOM seems correct, I can see that the button has ng-show="false" but for some reason I still see the button on screen** so it's as if Angular didn't know that it has to hide that element. The funny thing is that if I move to another tab, and I go back to the same tab (the view is reloaded and the directive re-executed) then it works fine. **What's going on?**.

I went with the option 2 and this is the code that seems to work properly manipulating the DOM, but Angular does not apply the ng-show directive afterwards therefor the result is not as expected.

```
public priority: number = 999; //High priority so it is executed BEFORE ng-show directive

public link(scope: ng.IScope, instanceElement: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, instanceAttributes: ng.IAttributes): void {
    let groupName: string = (<any>instanceAttributes).authorize;
    let element = angular.element(instanceElement);
    let ngShow: string = (<any>instanceAttributes).ngShow;
    let ngHide: string = (<any>instanceAttributes).ngHide;
    let hasGroup: boolean = this.authService.hasGroup(groupName);
    let ngHideValue = ngHide ? "!" + ngHide : "";
    let ngShowValue = ngShow ? ngShow : "";
    //if hasGroup, use whatever ng-show or ng-hide value the element had (ng-show = !ng-hide).
    //if !hasGroup, it does not matter what value the element had, it will be hidden.
    if (hasGroup) {
        element.attr("ng-show", (ngShowValue + ngHideValue) || "true");
    } else {
        element.attr("ng-show", "false");
    }
    element.removeAttr("ng-hide");
    //remove the attribute, otherwise it creates an infinite loop.
    element.removeAttr("authorize");
    this.$compile(element)(scope);
}
```

Comment: an obvious workaround is to wrap my button in a div and apply the `authorize` directive on the div itself, leaving the ng-hide in the button not to have conflict of multiple directives on the button itself. But I'd like to find a solution for my question and understand why angular does not re-compute `ng-show="false"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd argue that seeing as your `authorize` directive basically just controls whether the element that it's placed displays or not, you should just move its logic out into a service that you inject into your controller, and let `ng-hide` control whether the element displays like it's designed to.

This will be easier for developers who come later to understand - no one wants to go drilling down into individual directives to find various scattered bits of code that call the server, and your button then just looks like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" role="button"
    ng-hide="myVm.isDeleted || !myVm.isAuthorized(myVm.groupName)"
    ng-click="myVm.edit()">
    <span class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span> Edit
</button>
```

Nice and simple to read.

Comment: I agree with you, relying on `ng-hide` or `ng-show` to do what they know (hide or display elements) based on the result of the service seems a better and more readable solution, but it doesn't solve the problem with accessing vm properties in the directive's `link` function or with having angular re-compute DOM after my directive finalises since I gave it higher priority so I can't mark it as resolved :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you want to mess with the DOM pre-compilation, you can't do it in the link

Comment: Hmm... you've got a few problems then. As near as I can see, your vm propertiers _should_ be visible already, as there's no isolate scope. If in your solution you need to alter the DOM *prior* to compilation, you can't do it in the link function - you have to do it in a `compile` function as explained in the [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. About vm being visible (I should have mentioned that), it is. It's in the injected scope so I can access it with `scope.vm`. I didn't use that approach because the name of the controller in some views might be `vm` but in some other views it might be `otherVm` so I wanted to have some generic way to access it.

Comment: about using `compile` instead `link`, yes! it seems that'd be the way to achieve that now that I read its docs. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help :) While I still think your best bet is to move to using `ng-hide`, if you really do need to pass information on the `vm` to use into your directive you could try using another attribute to store the name of the property on your scope that your directive should reference.

Comment: I am already getting rid off my directive and using `ng-hide`/`ng-show` as suggested :-)
Passing an additional argument to the directive is a good option yep, I wanted to keep it as simple as possible but your suggestion not to use a custom directive for that seems the right thing to do anyway!